# When use custom layer in Tensorflow 2.0, the gradient returns None

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I designed a custom layer for use like this:

```
class SquaredWeightedLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=1):
        super(SquaredWeightedLayer, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)
        self.square_w = self.w ** 2
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)
        super(SquaredWeightedLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, self.square_w), self.b))
```

However, the `tape.gradient(loss, self.w)` returns `None` and `tape.gradient(loss, self.square_w)` returns normal value.
loss is `binary_crossentropy`.

I will very appreciate any suggestion for fixing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the computation of `self.w ** 2` is already executed in the `build` function, outside any tape context, so Tensorflow cannot trace that `square_w` actually came from `w`, leading to a gradient of `None`. You can fix it by simply moving the square operation into `call`:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w**2), self.b))
```

Comment: It does work,  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, consider accepting the answer so that other people can see it solves the issue!